# Why did the designers choose to include the Goliath as a PC race in Volo's Guide to Monsters?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, designer-reasons

I was looking through the new race options for PCs in *Volo's Guide to Monsters* and noticed they included the Goliath. About 2 years ago the Goliath was also published in the *Elemental Evil Player's Companion* supplement.

Comparing the two, there haven't been any updates or changes added in Volo's Guide.

So I'm left wondering: why did the designers decide to include a race that's already been published instead of creating a new one or just leaving it out?

My initial thought was that the Goliath might just be really popular and because the *Elemental Evil Player's Companion* is technically a supplement for the *Elemental Evil* story line, not many people would have bought it for use with any other campaign. But if that's the case, why *just* the Goliath? Why not the other races? Was it just because the Goliath won the popularity contest?

(I know the Aasimar is also include in Volo's Guide and the DMG but I have yet to compared the two to see if Volo's Guide is a more solidified option than what was suggested in the DMG).

Answers should cite **actual quotes from the designers** rather than speculating.

Comment: The Aasimar in the DMG is completely different to the Aasimar in Volo's. Also, deep gnomes were in both the EEPC and SCAG, well before the Goliath had this happen.

Comment: @Miniman huh, so they are. I hadn't noticed that. I guess my theory of Goliath popularity might hold, at least partially, true in my mind since I remembered the Goliath being in EEPC as soon as I saw it in Volo's Guide but never remembered the Deep Gnomes also being in EEPC when I looked through SCAG.

Comment: @Miniman That's probably because [the Aasimar in the DMG was just an example of building a new race](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/798298039395856384). It's even labeled "Example Race: Aasimar". You're right about deep gnomes, but they have different flavor text in SCAG that explicitly mentions Faerun (and their height was left out) while Goliaths were copied word-for-word.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [designer-reasons questions are no longer allowed on RPG.SE](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/questions-about-designer-reasons-are-off-topic).

Comment: @V2Blast Voting to reopen as the designer reason policy has been reverted.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin Please read through Someone_Evil's [post about this](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12158/62294), in particular: "Please leave old designer-reasons questions be until/unless they come up naturally. If there is a question that needs an updated answer (and is fine aside from the old policy), or if there is some other compelling reason to reopen it, do so. But we decidedly want to avoid bogging down the reopen queue (and the home page for that matter) with these old questions."

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Got it, no problem.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Mike Mearls did answer this question in an [Interview published on Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/toddkenreck/2016/11/14/inside-volos-guide-to-monsters/#508c2d5276e6)

> We reprinted the Goliath, we introduced them about a year ago in an online supplement and they're actually pretty popular when we look at what people are playing. We wanted to move them into a print book so there's more of a reference for people to use.

Comment: Fantastic find!